# this.prop.state.location.url is undefined? React Js Link Props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Component.js:**

```
<Link to={{ pathname: 'audio-Player', state: { url: 'Demo' } }}> Play</Link>
```

If I click this `Link` then the `AnitherComponent.js` opens and works but if I open this `AnitherComponent.js` direct, then it says **can not read property url at this.props.loaction.url**

**AnitherComponent.js:**

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.state.song.src = this.props.loaction.url
  console.log(this.state.song)
  this.setState({
    play_img: document.querySelector('#play_img'),
    range: document.querySelector('#range1'),
  })
  const { song, range, play_img, total_time, currentTime } = this.state
}
```

Comment: Hi! When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful info in it. There was also a toolbar full of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area showing what your post would look like when posted, between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, so you'd look at it). Making your post clear, and showing that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: **It's just a typo.** You have `loaction`, rather than `location`.

Comment: Please provide this export default withRouter(FirstComponent) at the bottom of first component

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access `loaction.url` which doesn't exist. You can set a default value if it doesn't exist:

```
this.state.song.src = this.props.loaction?.url ?? "default value";
```

or

```
this.state.song.src = this.props.loaction && this.props.loaction.url || "default value";
```

P.S. you might need plugin for the optional chaining.

Comment: Route components receive a `location` (not `loaction`) property. The OP's problem is a simple typo. We close typo-based questions.

Comment: I think Your syntex is wrong Can you replay it again

Comment: Well Thats Spelling Mistake too But  still getting same error

Comment: @adminuseonly - `??` is the [nullish coalescing operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-nullish-coalescing), a new addition to JavaScript.

Comment: In the first version of his post, he only had this piece of code, so I just went based on that. I guess you are right, it's a type but somehow it doesn't fix his problem? @T.J.Crowder